# How properly use functions in pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Sometimes when I use functions in `pyrogram` I receive the following output:

```
{
    "_": functionName,
    "argName" : value,
    "arg2Name" : value2,
    # etc.
}
```

For instance, If I write:

```
functions.users.GetFullUser(types.InputUserSelf())
```

I receive:

```
{
    "_": "functions.users.GetFullUser",
    "id": {
        "_": "types.InputUserSelf"
    }
}
```

Why do I receive this result? How should I properly use the functions?

Comment: And what is your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use send():

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.api import functions

app = Client("test")
result = app.send(functions.users.GetFullUser(types.InputUserSelf()))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Client.send()` method is now deprecated (Pyrogram v2.0), you should use [`Client.invoke()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/advanced-usage#invoking-functions).